# InteliJ 10 + Tomcat 7: Unable to access localhost:8080/manager/status

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, tomcat7

Currently have a setup of InteliJ10 + Tomcat 7 + Hibernate + Oracle.  I normally do my development and testing through InteliJ and the debugger.

I'm trying to navigate to `http://localhost:8080/manager/status`

However, I'm getting the error message:  401 Unauthorized.  I followed the instructions on the page and went to resolve the issue of creating a role of "manager-gui".  I've tried adding this to the conf/tmocat-users.xml file as instructed and tried to once again run my application in debug.

However, I still cannot access the page.  Looking at my Tomcat Log Output in InteliJ I'm seeing the following:

```
org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm authenticate
SEVER: Unexpected error
java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
...
```

Now I'd imagine this means I need to add some arguments to either my vm parameters for when I start up the server in debug OR go into my Debug Environment Variables and add something there to append JAVA_OPTS && CATALINA_OPTS.

The question is where?  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that IDEA makes a copy of your Tomcat configuration under [%SYSTEM%](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181)`\Tomcat\%CONFIGURATION%\conf` directory.

You need to restart the server after making the changes to the original Tomcat configuration, modified `tomcat-users.xml` copy should be available in the temp `CATALINA_BASE` directory after restart.

I've verified that it works fine. Another thing to check is that the line with `<user...` is not commented. Use some editor with the syntax highlighting to ensure that your user is defined outside of the comment block:

[image: tomcat-users.xml]

Comment: I went to C:\Users\myUserName\.IntelliJIdea10\system\tomcat\_coms\conf and made the edit to tomcat-users  However that didn't seem to fix it

I've restarted the server and even the machine and verified the file had been chaged.  Removed the comments and attempted to login as tomcat/tomcat

Still getting the you're not authorized to view the page...

Comment: Modify the original config, not the copy. Try again with a clean Tomcat installation.