# Can find resource (image) when TomEE is started from their startup script but failling from IntelliJ

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I am trying to access an image I have added at this directory `/home/username/.appname/users/img3.jpg` using my browser.

I am using `TomEE 1.7` and I've added this

```
<Context docBase="/home/chris/.harachi/users" path="/usersdir" />
```

At the `server.xml` file into the `Host` element.

When I start `TomEE` using the `tomEEDir/bin/catalina.sh start` command, I can view the image at this `URL: http://localhost:8080/usersdir/img3.jpg`.

Although, when I start an instance of `TomEE` from `IntelliJ IDEA` (13.1.4) I am getting a `HTTP Status 404 - /usersdir/img3.jpg` error message with `The requested resource is not available.` as a description.

What can I do?

**Notes:**

1. There are no errors at the logs
2. I've enabled SSL, tried with `8080` and `8443` ports, no success
3. Restarted `IntelliJ` as I saw ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884134/intelij-10-tomcat-7-unable-to-access-localhost8080-manager-status)) that it copies TomEE conf directory to some of theirs, still nothing
4. *Using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit, browser: Firefox*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, IntelliJ keeps a copy of some files of the server in their `config-dir/system/tomcat/appname/` (on linux, this is the path: `/home/username/.IntelliJIdea13/system/tomcat/app_name/`.

What fixed this, was checking the `Deploy applications configured in Tomcat Instance` at the Run configuration of the application, here:

[image: intellij idea run configuration]

So now, the image can be viewed now, at `localhost:port/usersdir/img3.jpg`.